# How do I Insert a Dictionary Object into Firebase Database with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a very simple DB in `Firebase` - What I would like to do is `insert` an `Array` or `Dictionary` into it. I have managed to do it but I can not imagine this is the right way.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let post7 : [String: String] = [
    "name" : "Michael",
    "city" : "Savannah",
    "age"  : "30"
]

let post8 : [String: String] = [
    "name" : "Angela",
    "city" : "London",
    "age"  : "21"
]



var dbReference: DatabaseReference?
//Connector used for query
var dbHandle : DatabaseHandle?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //insert Data from the dictionaries above post7 & post8

    dbReference = Database.database().reference()
    dbReference?.child("Person7").child("name").setValue(post7["name"])
    dbReference?.child("Person8").child("name").setValue(post8["name"])
    dbReference?.child("Person7").child("age").setValue(post7["age"])
    dbReference?.child("Person8").child("age").setValue(post8["age"])
    dbReference?.child("Person7").child("city").setValue(post7["city"])
    dbReference?.child("Person8").child("city").setValue(post8["city"])

    // Fetch Data and set it in the label
        dbHandle = dbReference?.child("name").observe(.childAdded,  with: { (snapshot)  in
            let name : String? = snapshot.value as? String
            print(name!)

    })
 }
```

}

[my firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoiET.png)

Comment: did you try dbReference?.child("Person7").updateChildValues(post7) ?

Comment: That was it - great answer and thanks.

Comment: Check the all `datatypes` `firebase` accepts. You're saving `String` value one by one instead of whole `Dictionary` at once. `Firebase` also accepts `Dictionary` and `Array` so make a `Dictionary` of person object and `dbReference?.child("Person7").setValue(person7Dictionary)`. Your way is okay if you need to update only single value like `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table for your persons. And do something like the following:

Declare a global instance of your reference

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

In your viewDidLoad

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

To insert your dictionary into Firebase, you should first set the path. (/Persons/7) and finally set the value you want to save.

```
ref.child("Persons").child("7").setValue(post7)
```

And to read the values one time from your DB

```
ref.child("Persons").child("7").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let username = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
  print(username)

  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```